# Silverlight 4 Non-Moveable or Non-Moveable Offscreen Child Window

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've read articles that Child Windows in SL3 cannot be set to non-moveable, without creating your own custom window.  Was this fixed in SL4?  This is a problem, because the user is able to drag windows off the silverlight stage, which seems like an awkard UI design.  On my first try I moved it offscreen and was not able to move it back or close it.  I do not understand the logic behind leaving out the option to make the window non-moveable.

Is there any other way to prevent the user from dragging a child window off the screen?  Or is creating my own custom window the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own custom Style which gets rid of the close button in the header and stops the moving.
In your control set: `<controls:ChildWindow ... Style="{StaticResource themeChildWindowStyle}"`

You can create the style with Blend pretty easy.

[Here's a discussion on this topic](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/154478/345466.aspx) which has another solution from "friendy1108"  ~"My solution right now is to hide the title bar and make a button to close the child window.
 From the link you sent, I can do this: title.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;" That would do it, but I prefer the style override.

Comment: Thanks, I might just hide the title, whatever is easiest.  It's good to know what the options are.